# How to go to a activity from list items?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

How can I go to another activity by clicking a list item?

```
myPDFListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("IntentReset")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            getSemesters getsemesters = getSemesters.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

This is my old code. With this code I'm able to view the PDF's. But now what I want is when I am clicking on a list item it should go to a new activity with passing a string to another activity. What should be changed? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a string you can use putExtra method

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("PDF_KEY", "SELECTED PDF VALUE");
startActivity(intent);
```

and use this to get the value in the opened activity

```
 getIntent().getStringExtra('PDF_KEY')
```

Edited:

the error showing because `this` here means the listener, try this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("PDF_KEY", "SELECTED PDF VALUE");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: By using this line intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); it will not go to another activity. We should provide the class names, but when I write the code in this form (Intent intent = new Intent(this, anyClassName.class);). It shows error.

Comment: @bhaskargogoi hi, try the new code

Answer (score 0):

To go to new Activity try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourNewActivityName.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "PDF VALUE");
startActivity(intent);
```

and to get this value in new Activity use

```
String value=getIntent().getStringExtra('PDF_KEY');
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier, But shows error.

Comment: then show the error you get dear